# PHP MCRYPT encrypt/decrypt returns invisible strange characters?

Tags: php, character, encryption, mcrypt

`mcrypt_decrypt` is giving me additional invisible characters which are NOT VISIBLE by just echoing out on the page. Can ONLY BE SEEN by writing it to the text file. Means, just displaying on the page is OK and hard to be noticed.

Here is the code sample by Googling. **Please guide me what is the correct usage is there's something wrong**:

```
function encrypt ($pure_string, $key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $pure_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

function decrypt ($encrypted_string, $key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted_string;
}
```

but when i try it:

```
$encrypted_string = encrypt("This is the original string.", "ABC123");
echo decrypt($encrypted_string, "ABC123");
```

.. i am getting something like:

```
This is the original string.�������
```

This strange characters `�������` are **actually not visible when** you/ i just `echo` it. Can only be seen by writing into the text file.

- So what am i missing please?
- Is there any perfect way to achieve this encrypt/decrypt?

Thank you.

Comment: `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` -- bad .. you should not be using this

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP decryption fails on some strings with trim()'s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518795/php-decryption-fails-on-some-strings-with-trims)

Comment: @Baba NO this is not a duplicate. Totally different problem. This is also not the `trim` issue.

Comment: Added it has duplicate because .. there so many issues with your encryption `MCRYPT_RAND ` , `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` lack of `PKCS7 padding` , `padding oracle attacks` .. you can lean a lot of the example class with having to duplicate the answer here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `trim($string, "\0\4")` to cut out these characters.

Comment: This works actually, even i'm not sure it is the good solution or not. At least the `�������` characters goes away.

Comment: You would have so many problems in future .. you proper padding  .. its not difficult

Answer (score 2):

This is padding. ECB mode requires input to be multiple of cipher block size, so additional bytes are added (most likely it is PKCS#5 padding).

To remove PKCS#5 padding you can use following code:

```
$dec_s = strlen($decrypted);
$padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s-1]);
$decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
```

Comment: So what is the correct usage please, since i really don't know.

Comment: o_O sorry but it is returning blank string `""`. Lets say `$decrypted = "This is the original string.�������"` . Also, is it about to put in the Decryption (after Decrypting the String) right?

Comment: Hm, what actually characters are at the end? Can you show the ord($decrypted[strlen($decrypted)-1]) ?

Answer (score 2):

rtrim() will remove the padding that mcrypt added...

Answer (score -2):

function encrypt ($pure_string, **$key**) {

**=>  $key**

$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, **$encryption_key**, $pure_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

**=> $encryption_key**

not equal

Comment: If its code example, please wrap it in appropriate way for highlighting and make sure syntax is correct. Also, little explanation is usually useful.